# Pyspark StreamingQueryListener QueryTerminatedEvent not fired when using delta tables

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a StreamingQueryListener using delta tables. When I try the [example](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/05/27/how-to-monitor-streaming-queries-in-pyspark.html) provided by databricks that is using csv's instead of delta tables everything works as expected. However when I try to a similar thing using delta tables, the QueryTerminatedEvent is not fired or will throw an error. Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong and how I can solve it?

Error:

```
23/06/09 10:34:08 ERROR StreamingQueryListenerBus: Listener PythonStreamingQueryListenerWrapper threw an exception
py4j.Py4JException: Error while sending a command.
        at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:397)
        at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:356)
        at py4j.reflection.PythonProxyHandler.invoke(PythonProxyHandler.java:106)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.onQueryTerminated(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.PythonStreamingQueryListenerWrapper.onQueryTerminated(StreamingQueryListener.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryListenerBus.doPostEvent(StreamingQueryListenerBus.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryListenerBus.doPostEvent(StreamingQueryListenerBus.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus.postToAll$(ListenerBus.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryListenerBus.postToAll(StreamingQueryListenerBus.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryListenerBus.onOtherEvent(StreamingQueryListenerBus.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus.doPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus.doPostEvent$(SparkListenerBus.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.doPostEvent(AsyncEventQueue.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.doPostEvent(AsyncEventQueue.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus.postToAll$(ListenerBus.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.super$postToAll(AsyncEventQueue.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.$anonfun$dispatch$1(AsyncEventQueue.scala:105)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$2.$anonfun$run$1(AsyncEventQueue.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1471)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$2.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:96)
Caused by: py4j.Py4JNetworkException: Error while sending a command: c
p0
onQueryTerminated
ro180
e

        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.sendCommand(ClientServerConnection.java:253)
        at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:384)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: py4j.Py4JException: Received empty command
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.sendCommand(ClientServerConnection.java:236)
        ... 25 more
23/06/09 10:34:08 ERROR StreamingQueryListenerBus: Listener PythonStreamingQueryListenerWrapper threw an exception
py4j.Py4JException: Error while obtaining a new communication channel
        at py4j.CallbackClient.getConnectionLock(CallbackClient.java:257)
        at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:377)
        at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:356)
        at py4j.reflection.PythonProxyHandler.invoke(PythonProxyHandler.java:106)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.onQueryTerminated(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.PythonStreamingQueryListenerWrapper.onQueryTerminated(StreamingQueryListener.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryListenerBus.doPostEvent(StreamingQueryListenerBus.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryListenerBus.doPostEvent(StreamingQueryListenerBus.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus.postToAll$(ListenerBus.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryListenerBus.postToAll(StreamingQueryListenerBus.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryListenerBus.onOtherEvent(StreamingQueryListenerBus.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus.doPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus.doPostEvent$(SparkListenerBus.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.doPostEvent(AsyncEventQueue.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.doPostEvent(AsyncEventQueue.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus.postToAll$(ListenerBus.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.super$postToAll(AsyncEventQueue.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.$anonfun$dispatch$1(AsyncEventQueue.scala:105)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$2.$anonfun$run$1(AsyncEventQueue.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1471)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$2.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:96)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:454)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:264)
        at java.base/javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:277)
        at py4j.PythonClient.startClientSocket(PythonClient.java:192)
        at py4j.PythonClient.getConnection(PythonClient.java:213)
        at py4j.CallbackClient.getConnectionLock(CallbackClient.java:250)
        ... 25 more
```

Working csv example:

```py
my_csv_dir = "tmp/"
# Now, start a streaming query that monitors 'my_csv_dir' directory.
# Every time when there are new CSV files arriving here, we will process them.
my_csv = spark.readStream.schema(
    "my_key INT, my_val DOUBLE, _corrupt_record STRING"
).csv(Path(my_csv_dir).as_uri())
# `DataFrame.observe` computes the counts of processed and malformed records,
# and sends an event to the listener.
my_observed_csv = my_csv.observe(
    "metric",
    f.count(f.lit(1)).alias("cnt"),  # number of processed rows
    f.count(f.col("_corrupt_record")).alias("malformed"))  # number of malformed rows
my_csv = some_logic(my_csv)
my_query = my_csv.writeStream.foreachBatch(some_logic).format(
    "console").queryName("My observer").start()
my_csv = some_logic(my_csv)
my_query = my_csv.writeStream.foreachBatch(some_logic).format(
    "console").queryName("My observer").start()



# Now, we will write CSV data to be processed in a streaming manner on time.
# This CSV file is all well-formed.
with open(os.path.join(my_csv_dir, "my_csv_1.csv"), "w") as f:
    _ = f.write("1,1.1\n")
    _ = f.write("123,123.123\n")

time.sleep(5)  # Assume that another CSV file arrived in 5 seconds.

# Ouch! it has two malformed records out of 3. My observer query should alert it!
with open(os.path.join(my_csv_dir, "my_csv_error.csv"), "w") as f:
    _ = f.write("1,1.123\n")
    _ = f.write("Ouch! malformed record!\n")
    _ = f.write("Arrgggh!\n")

time.sleep(3)  # OK, all done. Let's stop the query in 5 seconds.
spark.streams.removeListener(my_listener)
```

Not working delta example:

```py
from pyspark.sql.streaming import StreamingQueryListener
from pyspark.sql.streaming.listener import (
    QueryStartedEvent,
    QueryProgressEvent,
    QueryTerminatedEvent,
)
import pyspark
import time
from delta import configure_spark_with_delta_pipimport pyspark
import time
from delta import configure_spark_with_delta_pip

builder = (
    pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp")
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
    .config(
        "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog",
        "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog",
    )
)

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
input_table = "spark/input"
output_table =" spark/output"
mydata1 = "tmp/data_dump/part-00000-17f59480-16e2-418a-960e-285fdd04ee45.c000.snappy.parquet"
mydata2 = "tmp/data_dump/part-00000-248f4fb4-7c85-4b13-baaf-0689b57e54c2.c000.snappy.parquet"

class CustomListener(StreamingQueryListener):
    def onQueryStarted(self, event):
        """
        Called when a query is started.

        Parameters
        ----------
        event: :class:`pyspark.sql.streaming.listener.QueryStartedEvent`
            The properties are available as the same as Scala API.

        Notes
        -----
        This is called synchronously with
        meth:`pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start`,
        that is, ``onQueryStart`` will be called on all listeners before
        ``DataStreamWriter.start()`` returns the corresponding
        :class:`pyspark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery`.
        Do not block in this method as it will block your query.
        """
        print("STARTED")

    def onQueryProgress(self, event):
        """
        Called when there is some status update (ingestion rate updated, etc.)

        Parameters
        ----------
        event: :class:`pyspark.sql.streaming.listener.QueryProgressEvent`
            The properties are available as the same as Scala API.

        Notes
        -----
        This method is asynchronous. The status in
        :class:`pyspark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery` will always be
        latest no matter when this method is called. Therefore, the status
        of :class:`pyspark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery`.
        may be changed before/when you process the event.
        For example, you may find :class:`StreamingQuery`
        is terminated when you are processing `QueryProgressEvent`.
        """
        print("PROGRESS")

    def onQueryTerminated(self, event):
        """
        Called when a query is stopped, with or without error.

        Parameters
        ----------
        event: :class:`pyspark.sql.streaming.listener.QueryTerminatedEvent`
            The properties are available as the same as Scala API.
        """
        print("ENDED")

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
mylistener = CustomListener()
spark.streams.addListener(mylistener)
batch_df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(
    mydata1
)
#create source delta table
batch_df.write.format("delta").save(input_table)
#create target delta table
batch_df.write.format("delta").save(output_table)


df = spark.readStream.format("delta").load(
    input_table
)
q = (df.writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("delta")
    .trigger(**{"processingTime": "1 seconds"})
    .start(output_table)
)

time.sleep(5)
print("extra data")
batch_df2 = spark.read.format("parquet").load(
    mydata2
)
batch_df2.write.format("delta").mode("append").save(input_table)
time.sleep(5)
q.stop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the program exited before the query terminated event was able fire the event. By adding `time.sleep(5)` just after `q.stop()` solved the issue.